# Установка приложения через ADB

Tags: java, android

**Дано:**  название пакета из `Google Play` к примеру (`details?id=com.whatsapp`)

**Задача:** установить это приложение на устройство автоматически, т.е. написал имя пакета и приложение установилось на устройство, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: никак. Максимум это переходить в маркет через интент по указанной ссылке

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, я ADB не юзал пользуюсь genymotion, сказали что можно скрипт написать для ADB, вы не знаете хоть куда копать нужно или что почитать))

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, там вроде есть команда `adb install <path_to_apk>`, в этот `<path_to_apk> `нельзя вставить ссылку на маркет?

Comment: это путь, который ссылается на уже скачанную apk. Я думаю что Ваша задача невыполнима. Взять даже то, что приложения бывают платными и бесплатными, и чтобы чё то скачать, надо быть залогининым в гугле

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, то что надо быть залогининым в гугле это ясно, ведь устройство уже будет залогининым, и по поводу приложений в моей задаче рассматриваются бесплатные приложения

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот вопрос уже задавался [здесь (англ)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61541/installing-an-app-from-play-store-using-the-command-line)

Если подытожить то что сказано в ответах, то **нельзя установить ничего из маркета автоматически**. Но можно открыть маркет из командной строки:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d 'market://details?id=com.myapp'
```

Либо скачать .apk файл при помощи apk downloader и установить используя `adb install`